# how do I align an image to center?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm doing a simple test website to practice html. These are the image align variants I've tried that haven't worked:

```
 <style type="text/css">
      img {
      image-align: center;
      border: 2px dashed gray;
      height: 200px;
      width:  140px;

      }
 </style>
```

---

```
 <img src="images/htmlphoto2.jpg" alt="profile pic of man wearing tie" align="middle"/>
```

---

```
 <style type="text\css">
     img {
       margin-right: auto;
       margin-left: auto;
     }
```

```
  <style type="text\css"> 
     img {
       display: block;
       margin: 0 auto;
     }
  </style>
```

---

full code: I'm using a combination of internal style sheet and inline styling for practice.

```
 <!-- autobiobrevio -->
 <!-- 8/21/14 11:00 - 11:50 Structure completed -->
 <!--8/23/14 10:00 pm - Alignment -->

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>biosite</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1  {
          text-align: center;
        }

       img {
          image-align: center;
          border: 2px dashed gray;
          height: 200px;
          width:  140px;
       }

    </style>

 </head>

 <body>

 <h1> Steve's Autobiobrevio </h1>

<img src="images/htmlphoto2.jpg" alt="profile pic of guy wearing tie" />
<br>
<br>

  <table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <ul> <span style="font-family: Impact"> De moi </span>
        <li> Born October 1972 </li>
        <li> CT </li>
        <li> blah blah blah </li>
       </ul>
    </td>

     <td>
       <ul> <span style="font-family: Impact"> Hobbies </span>  
        <li> Guitar </li>
        <li> HTML </li>
        <li> Hiking </li>
       </ul>
     </td>

    <td>
      <ul>  <span style="font-family: Impact"> Fav Guitarists </span>
       <li> David Gilmour </li>
       <li> Muddy Waters </li>
       <li> Dave Navarro </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
 </table>

  <div style="width: 800px; height: 100px; background-color: red" </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: try to put `img` tag in `<center><img src="" ...></center>`

Comment: @Farshad the `<center>` tag has been deprecated.

Comment: `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 2):

try to add `display:block` to your

**html :**

```
<img src="http://farshadajdar.com/imgeditor/tweety.png" class="displayed" alt="profile pic of man wearing tie" align="middle"/>
```

**css :**

```
img.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DMEO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vpvnqatu/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the full html code?Anyway
First remove align="middle " and try this even if it's similar to yours

```
img{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;

     }
```

Comment: i added the full code; and i solved the problem by using this code on the image:  <img src="images/htmlphoto2.jpg" alt="profile pic of guy wearing tie" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" />

Comment: remove the "/" from the end of the img tag and then use my css code,eg:<img src="" alt="">

Answer (score 0):

Try this,It Will definately work..

Image Code :

```
<img src="http://farshadajdar.com/imgeditor/tweety.png" class="displayed" alt="profile pic of man wearing tie"/>
```

Here goes the css :

```
<style type=text/css>
img.displayed {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -100px;
}
</style>
```

Hop it will work for you too..

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
<style type="text/css">
    img {
    position:absolute;
    border:2px dashed gray;
    height:200px;
    width:140px;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0; 
    }
 </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by using the inline style tag:

But why didn't the inline style sheet work?